# Stream stdout from scala Process

Tags: python, scala

I am using scala Process to kick off a python program and using ProcessLogger to capture the stdout from the python program. I see that the print statements in the python program are printed only after the python program completes. Is there a way to stream the python print statements as they are executed ?

```
import scala.sys.process.{ProcessLogger, _}

object TestProcessStdOut {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    var cmd = "python python_test.py";
    val process = Process(cmd).run(new ProcessLogger {
      override def out(s: => String) = println(s)

      override def buffer[T](f: => T) = ???

      override def err(s: => String) = ???
    })
  }
}
```

python_test.py

```
import time

print("print data 1")
time.sleep(2)
print("print data 2")
time.sleep(2)
print("print data 3")
time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: I would suggest looking into modifying the Python program to *not* buffer output. If the Python program buffers output, it only prints out at the end, so the Scala program cannot read what the Python program has not printed.

Comment: @radumanolescu i cannot modify the python program since it can be submitted by different people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tell python not to buffer your output in scala with `-u` will help you:

```
var cmd = "python -u python_test.py"
```