# Process Interaction through stdin/stdout

Tags: scala, process, io

I am trying to build a class that starts a system process which waits for stdin. The class should have another method which takes a string, inputs that into the system process, and return the process' output.

The reason is that starting the process involves loading a lot of data and hence takes a while.
I am trying to dummy-test this with `bc`, so that `bc` is started and waits for input. I would envision an interface like this:

```
case class BcWrapper(executable: File) {
  var bc: Option[???] = None

  def startBc(): Unit = bc = Some(???)

  def calc(input: String): String = bc.get.???

  def stopBc(): Unit = bc.get.???
}
```

I would like to be able to use it like this:

```
val wrapper = BcWrapper(new File("/usr/bin/bc"))
wrapper.startBc()
val result1 = wrapper.calc("1 + 1") // should be "2"
val result2 = wrapper.calc(???)
[...]
wrapper.stopBc()
```

This topic has been touched in multiple questions, but never fully answered for a use case like this one. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42864697/stream-stdout-from-scala-process) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22885837/how-can-i-supply-input-for-an-external-command) seems to come close. However, I am not sure how to implement the `ProcessLogger`, nor whether to use one in the first place.

Unfortunately, the [Scala documentation](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.5/scala/sys/process/index.html) is not very elaborate either.

Note that I do not want to read from stdin, but want to call a function.

The background is that I want to read a large file, read it line by line, preprocess the lines, pass them to the external process, and post-process the output.

Comment: You can check out akka actors and make each task to be implemented inside of actors and use their ask and wait pattern, that will eventually give you the output. I can post a step by step algorithm, if you want.

Comment: @zenwraight thanks for the suggestion! It remains a bit unclear to me though why/how I should have to apply Akka Actors. This actually seems like a rather simple task, in which features like parallelization is not necessary at this point. So if you have a step-by-step solution at hand, that might indeed help me.

Comment: Ya it's not necessary but makes your whole design more modular, can you also post an example input and output for the above process.Like what a file looks like and what it the final output etc..

Comment: This link has examples on using scala.sys.process. You can run programs, write stdin and read stdout.

Comment: @JohnHanley which link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get something similar, but simpler, like so.

```
import sys.process._
import util.Try

class StdInReader(val reader :String) {
  def send(input :String) :Try[String] =
    Try(s"/bin/echo $input".#|(reader).!!.trim)
}
```

usage:

```
val bc = new StdInReader("/usr/bin/bc")
bc.send("2 * 8")   //res0: scala.util.Try[String] = Success(16)
bc.send("12 + 8")  //res1: scala.util.Try[String] = Success(20)
bc.send("22 - 8")  //res2: scala.util.Try[String] = Success(14)
```

Programs that send a non-zero exit-code (`bc` doesn't) will result with a `Failure()`.

If you need more fine-grained control you might start with something like this and expand on it.

```
import sys.process._

class ProcHandler(val cmnd :String) {
  private val resbuf = collection.mutable.Buffer.empty[String]
  def run(data :Seq[String]) :Unit = {
    cmnd.run(new ProcessIO(
      in => {
        val writer = new java.io.PrintWriter(in)
        data.foreach(writer.println)
        writer.close()
      },
      out => {
        val src = io.Source.fromInputStream(out)
        src.getLines().foreach(resbuf += _)
        src.close()
      },
      _.close()  //maybe create separate buffer for stderr?
    )).exitValue()
  }
  def results() :Seq[String] = {
    val rs = collection.mutable.Buffer.empty[String]
    resbuf.copyToBuffer(rs)
    resbuf.clear()
    rs
  }
}
```

usage:

```
val bc = new ProcHandler("/usr/bin/bc")
bc.run(List("4+5","6-2","2*5"))
bc.run(List("99/3","11*77"))
bc.results()  //res0: Seq[String] = ArrayBuffer(9, 4, 10, 33, 847)
```

---

OK, I did some more research and found this. It appears to get at what you want but there are limitations. In particular, the process stays open for input until you want to get output. At that point IO streams are closed to insure all buffers are flushed.

```
import sys.process._
import util.Try

class ProcHandler(val cmnd :String) {
  private val procInput = new java.io.PipedOutputStream()
  private val procOutput = new java.io.PipedInputStream()
  private val proc = cmnd.run( new ProcessIO(
    { in => // attach to the process's internal input stream
      val istream = new java.io.PipedInputStream(procInput)
      val buf = Array.fill(100)(0.toByte)
      Iterator.iterate(istream.read(buf)){ br =>
        in.write(buf, 0, br)
        istream.read(buf)
      }.takeWhile(_>=0).toList
      in.close()
    },
    { out => // attach to the process's internal output stream
      val ostream = new java.io.PipedOutputStream(procOutput)
      val buf = Array.fill(100)(0.toByte)
      Iterator.iterate(out.read(buf)){ br =>
        ostream.write(buf, 0, br)
        out.read(buf)
      }.takeWhile(_>=0).toList
      out.close()
    },
    _ => () // ignore stderr
  ))
  private val procO = new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(procOutput))
  private val procI = new java.io.PrintWriter(procInput, true)
  def feed(str :String) :Unit = procI.println(str)
  def feed(ss :Seq[String]) :Unit = ss.foreach(procI.println)
  def read() :List[String] = {
    procI.close()  //close input before reading output
    val lines = Stream.iterate(Try(procO.readLine)){_ =>
      Try(procO.readLine)
    }.takeWhile(_.isSuccess).map(_.get).toList
    procO.close()
    lines
  }
}
```

usage:

```
val bc = new ProcHandler("/usr/bin/bc")
bc.feed(List("9*3","4+11"))  //res0: Unit = ()
bc.feed("4*13")              //res1: Unit = ()
bc.read()                    //res2: List[String] = List(27, 15, 52)
bc.read()                    //res3: List[String] = List()
```

---

OK, this is my final word on the subject. I think this ticks every item on your wish list: start the process only once, it stays alive until actively closed, allows alternating the writing and reading.

```
import sys.process._

class ProcHandler(val cmnd :Seq[String]) {
  private var os: java.io.OutputStream = null
  private var is: java.io.InputStream = null
  private val pio = new ProcessIO(os = _, is = _, _.close())
  private val proc = cmnd.run(pio)
  def feed(ss :String*) :Unit = {
    ss.foreach(_.foreach(os.write(_)))
    os.flush()
  }
  def ready :Boolean = is.available() > 0
  def read() :String = {
    Seq.fill[Char](is.available())(is.read().toChar).mkString
  }
  def close() :Unit = {
    proc.exitValue()
    os.close()
    is.close()
  }
}
```

There are still issues and much room for improvement. IO is handled at a basic level (streams) and I'm not sure what I'm doing here is completely safe and correct. The input, `feed()`, is required to supply the necessary NewLine terminations, and the output, `read()`, is just a raw `String` and not separated into a nice collection of string results.

Note that this will bleed system resources if the client code fails to `close()` all processes.

Note also that reading doesn't wait for content (i.e. no blocking). After writing the response might not be immediately available.

usage:

```
val bc = new ProcHandler(Seq("/usr/bin/bc","-q"))
bc.feed("44-21\n", "21*4\n")
bc.feed("67+11\n")
if (bc.ready) bc.read() else "not ready" // "23\n84\n78\n"
bc.feed("67-11\n")
if (bc.ready) bc.read() else "not ready"  // "56\n"
bc.feed("67*11\n", "1+2\n")
if (bc.ready) bc.read() else "not ready"  // "737\n3\n"
if (bc.ready) bc.read() else "not ready"  // "not ready"
bc.close()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! However, both solutions seem to start the process on every `run` call, don't they? The whole idea was to run it once and keep it in memory, while reading input from stdin.

Comment: This looks good, thanks a lot! Only thing that does not work is alternate writing and reading, e.g.: `bc.feed("1+1"); bc.read(); bc.feed("2+2"); bc.read()`. The last `read()` call returns an empty list.

Comment: Note that `is` and `os` are set by a sub-thread. Thus you might like to add something like `while(proc.isAlive() && (is == null || os == null)) Thread.sleep(1)`. I needed this, because I wrapped the streams with an `PrintWriter` and a `BufferedReader` after starting the process. @jwvh: BTW: Imo your last answer should go to the top, as it's the correct answer to the OPs question.